# Can you make a custom localhost?

Tags: web, dns, webserver, localhost

Ok here's my question, if you have a web server installed and running on your machine you can type localhost into a web browser and be taken to 127.0.0.1 please correct me if I'm wrong.
But my question is this, could I make a custom address where I type in mywebsite:com and be directed to my website via a DNS server, the colon instead of the . was intentional.

Thanks in advance,
Francis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a colon ':' in a host name. Therefore 'mywebsite:com' would not work, because the browser would try to interpret 'com' as a TCP port, and that would fail, as it's not a number.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add an entry in the /etc/hosts file like this to access localhost via a domain name.

`127.0.0.1       mydomain.com`

If you are using windows then you can find hosts file in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.

-MS

Answer (score 0):

I've always wanted to do the same thing, now what you do is go to(assuming you are on windows) C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc and edit the hosts file,
but since the file is write protected you will have to copy the file, edit it in some other folder then bring it back and delete the original one;
from:
127.0.0.1 localhost
to:
127.0.0.1 *your desired domain name*
now fire up your server, go to your browser and voila!